# Files missing from bundler docs generation

Tags: ruby, bundler

When I run `bundle` to generate my docs I notice that `file.CHANGELOG.html` and `AWS/Config` do not exist in the generated files but they previously did. How can I get these to generate again?

Comment: What tool do you use to generate docs?

Comment: I'm using `Bundler`

Comment: Bundler doesn't generate documentation, so it must be something else, can you show your `Gemfile` or gemspec file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `.yardocs` file was not configured correctly.